# Can you change decoded format with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to play some videos from my external hard drive onto my TV. However, it seems Planar 4:2:0 YUV 10 bit LE is too demanding for my TV. The video codec for my videos are h264. I have some other videos that are h264 and are able to run on my TV. When I open them on VLC, their decoded format is blank. The problem just occurs when the decoded format is YUV 10-bit.

I'm not too familiar with ffmpeg and I'm not sure what commands I need or if it's possible to change the decoded format.

Answer (score 4):

Basic command to get 8-bit standard YUV 4:2:0 is

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p +movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had some video which VLC codec information showed as with

```
Planar 4:2:0 YUV 10 bit LE
```

For my raspberry 3 along with x265 to h264, I had to add the : `-pix_fmt yuv420p` (Credits to @Gyan)

Full command:

```
ffmpeg -i $FILEIN  -map 0 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p $FILEOUT
```